# How To Override A Variable In A Form And Submit

Tags: php, yii

I'm working on a password reset form that has the following fields

```
<==Username==>
<==Current Password==>
<==New Password==>
<==Confirm Password==>
```

**View code**

```
  <div class="row"><?php 
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); 
    echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>150)); 
    echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
  </div>    

  <div class="row"><?php         
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'Current password');
    $model->password="";
    echo $form->textField($model,'password',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>150)); 
    echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row"><?php   
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'New password');
    $model->password="";
    echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>150)); 
    echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
  </div>

   <div class="row">  
   <?php echo $form->label($model,'password_repeat'); ?>    
   <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password_repeat',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>150)); ?>    
   <?php echo $form->error($model,'password_repeat'); ?> 
   </div>

   <div class="row buttons"><?php 
    echo CHtml::submitButton('Reset Your Password');
    ?></div><?php
```

**Controller code**

```
    public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);

// set the parameters for the bizRule
$params = array('GroupzSupport'=>$model);
// now check the bizrule for this user
if (!Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('updateSelf', $params) &&
    !Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('admin'))
{
    throw new CHttpException(403, 'You are not authorized to perform this action');
}
  else
{

   if(isset($_POST['GroupzSupport']))
    {                        
        $model->attributes=$_POST['GroupzSupport'];
                    $model->password = $model->hashPassword($_POST['GroupzSupport']['password']);
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('admin','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
}
```

I have the following password field that needs to be updated into database. I need to use password variable for new password field. 
   Now, I need to override the current password to new password and save it. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the correct way to do the password reset. Since the same $password field is used for "Current Password" and "New Password", when the form is posted you'll only have access to "New Password" as it will override the "Current Password". Hence you'll not be able to verify if the user's current password is valid. So the best way forward is to create a separate model called "ChangePassword.php" in your models folder with the following code,

ChangePassword.php

```
/**
 * Password change class.
 */
class ChangePassword extends CFormModel
{
    public $password;
    public $new_password;
    public $password_repeat;
    public $username;

    public function rules(){
        return array(
            array('username, password, new_password, password_repeat', 'required'), // Required fields
            array('password_repeat','compare','compareAttribute'=>'password', 'message'=> 'Passwords don\'t match!'), // Validator to check if the new password and password repeat match.
            array('password', 'isValid'), // Custom validator to check if the current password is valid.
        );
    }

    public function isValid($attribute, $params){
        if(!$this->hasErrors()){
            if($user = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username))){ // Fetch the user model using username.
                if($user->password !== Yii::app()->utils->hash($this->old_password)){ // Check if the current password is valid
                    $this->addError('password', 'Current Password is invalid!');
                }
            }
            else
                $this->addError('username', 'User does not exist!');
        }
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'username'=>'Username',
            'password'=>'Current password',
            'new_password' => 'New password',
            'password_repeat' => 'Confirm password'
        );
    }
}
```

Modify your controller code as,

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = new ChangePassword;

    // set the parameters for the bizRule
    $params = array('GroupzSupport'=>$model);
    // now check the bizrule for this user
    if (!Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('updateSelf', $params) && !Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('admin'))
    {
        throw new CHttpException(403, 'You are not authorized to perform this action');
    }
    else
    {
       if(isset($_POST['ChangePassword']))
       {                        
            $model->attributes=$_POST['ChangePassword'];               
            if($model->validate()){ // If all the information entered were correct
                $user = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$model->username));
                $user->password = hashPasswordFunction($model->password); // Call the function to hash your password which in most of the cases will be md5($model->password)
                $user->save();
            }
        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
}
```

Now your view file will change to,

```
<div class="row"><?php 
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); 
    echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>150)); 
    echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row"><?php         
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'Current password');
    echo $form->textField($model,'password',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>150)); 
    echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row"><?php   
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'New password');
    echo $form->passwordField($model,'new_password',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>150)); 
    echo $form->error($model,'new_password'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">  
    <?php echo $form->label($model,'password_repeat'); ?>    
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password_repeat',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>150)); ?>    
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'password_repeat'); ?> 
</div>
<div class="row buttons"><?php 
    echo CHtml::submitButton('Reset Your Password');
?></div>
```